# Show notification text in status bar on Android 6

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, 4.4-kitkat, notifications, notification-bar

On Android 4 when I'd get a notification (email, text, etc) it would briefly flash the notification text in the status bar, like who the email was from and the subject, or the first line of the text message.

I got a new phone with android 6 and it doesn't seem to be doing that.

How do I make it do that?

I couldn't find the setting in the notifications area of settings.

Comment: Have you checked if lock screen is allowed to set notifications (in advanced settings) when screen is locked?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Yeah, I played with that setting with similar hopes, but it doesn't make a difference.